# TALEND : How to log component level runtime information

Tags: talend

Consider the below image part of my talend job

[image]

I am aware of the advanced setting int Talend Studio.[image]

I want to be able to log output the ***whole runtime dynamic values substituted in the query*** for CREATE_RULE_TICKET component .

For example lets say the component has the following query

```
 SELECT START_DATE  FROM  TABLENAME WHERE CIF IN ('"+globalMap.get("cif")+')
```

The log should show me the runtime value for CIF

```
SELECT START_DATE  FROM  TABLENAME WHERE CIF IN ('HU8909','JKO98')
```

How do we go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The component has a global variable QUERY, which returns your query after it has been constructed, so you can log it in a tJava like:

```
tHiveRow -- OnComponentOk -- tJava (System.out.println((String)globalMap.get("tHiveRow_1_QUERY"));)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! However the right way is `System.out.println(((String)globalMap.get("tHiveRow_10_QUERY")));`

Comment: Indeed; I answered from my mobile, I forgot to include the globalMap part and the cast to String :) I've corrected my answer

Comment: Plus u hd missed the globalMap variable too :-p